# Regex for Managed Metadata Format (Multiple Values)

Tags: regex

I have got this regex which gives the description of a single input value:

```
(?:GTSET|GP0|GPP|L0)\|#0[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]*\|(.*)

L0|#060066230-11f1-46db-ad89-2b91ffd42ec4|Processing
```

But when it comes to multiple values - it doesnt work - whats missing ?

```
GP0|#3e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57;L0|#03‌​e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a6‌​8a-3ccb18f72e57|Argu‌​mentationshilfen;GTS‌​et|#25b6d12b-8e8b-42‌​33-8931-9c50587ca114‌​;GP0|#84e33f19-dc80-‌​4628-b292-a96090b1c7‌​02;L0|#084e33f19-dc8‌​0-4628-b292-a96090b1‌​c702|Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder)

GP0|#3e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57;L0|#03e7ea87a-6d25‌​-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72‌​e57|Argumentationshi‌​lfen;GTSet|#25b6d12b‌​-8e8b-4233-8931-9c50‌​587ca114;GP0|#84e33f‌​19-dc80-4628-b292-a9‌​6090b1c702;L0|#084e3‌​3f19-dc80-4628-b292-‌​a96090b1c702|Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder);GP0|#a8629bc7-a09f-4c45-a864-8506e0‌​01ef66;L0|#0a8629bc7‌​-a09f-4c45-a864-8506‌​e001ef66|Technische Daten"
```

Comment: What do you expect to obtain for each string above? What is the code behind the regex?

Comment: Suppose for below input: I should get Processing `L0|#060066230-11f1-46db-ad89-2b91ffd42ec4|Processing
`

Comment: Now for the below multiple value, I should get: Argu‌​mentationshilfen - Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder) `GP0|#3e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57;L0|#03‌​e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a6‌​8a-3ccb18f72e57|Argu‌​mentationshilfen;GTS‌​et|#25b6d12b-8e8b-42‌​33-8931-9c50587ca114‌​;GP0|#84e33f19-dc80-‌​4628-b292-a96090b1c7‌​02;L0|#084e33f19-dc8‌​0-4628-b292-a96090b1‌​c702|Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder)
`

Comment: code behind the regex is Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to restrict the `(.*)` pattern that matches any 0+ chars other than line breaks with a negated character class that matches any 1+ chars other than `;`, `[^;]+` (since it seems to be the delimiter for the values you need to extract).

Use

```
(?:GTSET|GP0|GPP|L0)\|#0[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]*\|([^;]+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XH1ews/1). Note I also contracted the pattern a bit by merging three `-[0-9a-f]{4}` into `(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}` (3 occurrences of `-<4_HEX_CHARS>` sequences).

```js
var rx = /(?:GTSET|GP0|GPP|L0)\|#0[0-9a-f]{8}(?:-[0-9a-f]{4}){3}-[0-9a-f]*\|([^;]+)/g;
var strs = [ 'L0|#060066230-11f1-46db-ad89-2b91ffd42ec4|Processing', 'GP0|#3e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57;L0|#03e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57|Argumentationshilfen;GTSet|#25b6d12b-8e8b-4233-8931-9c50587ca114;GP0|#84e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702;L0|#084e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702|Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder)', 'GP0|#3e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57;L0|#03e7ea87a-6d25-4f18-a68a-3ccb18f72e57|Argumentationshilfen;GTSet|#25b6d12b-8e8b-4233-8931-9c50587ca114;GP0|#84e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702;L0|#084e33f19-dc80-4628-b292-a96090b1c702|Medien (Videos/Grafiken/Bilder);GP0|#a8629bc7-a09f-4c45-a864-8506e001ef66;L0|#0a8629bc7-a09f-4c45-a864-8506e001ef66|Technische Daten'];

for (var s of strs) {
  var res = [], m;
  while (m=rx.exec(s)) {
     res.push(m[1]);
  }
  console.log(res);
}
```

Also, note that the `(?:GTSET|GP0|GPP|L0)` group is better written as `(?:G(?:TSET|P[0P])|L0)` to avoid redundant backtracking.